# How does react-transition-group CSSTransition work?

Tags: reactjs, animation, react-transition-group, web-animations, react-animations

So I'm trying to use react-transition-group to animate the transition between the different sections of an app.

I have the component I want to animate in the CSSTransition component in the following way:

```
       return (
        <CSSTransition in={showDepSearchResults} timeout={3000} classNames="fade" onEntered={() => showDepSearchResults(true)} onExit={() => showDepSearchResults(false)} >
            <div className='searchResult' key='searchResult'>


                <FlightSearchParameters flightSearchParams={flightSearchParams} typeOfDepartureDate={typeOfDepartureDate} typeOfReturnDate={typeOfReturnDate} typeOfTripSwitch={typeOfTripSwitch} formatPlaces={formatPlaces}/>

                <h1>Vuelos {typeOfSearchTittle()} disponibles:</h1>
                {showFlights()}
                <button className='btn btn-secondary' onClick={(e) => handleSearchAgain(e)}>Buscar más vuelos</button>

            </div>
        </CSSTransition>
    )
}
```

Also, I have the following code in my CSS:

```
.fade-appear {
    opacity: 0;
}

.fade-appear-active {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 3000ms;
}

.fade-enter {
    opacity: 0;
}

.fade-enter-active {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 3000ms;
}

.fade-exit {
    opacity: 1;
}

.fade-exit-active {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 3000ms;
}
```

For some reason I can't yet understand this is not working.
Does anyone have an answer for this?

The whole code is available here: https://github.com/coccagerman/bond

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I was also having some trouble with this library. I am curious if you have tried adding the `appear` attribute to `<CSSTransition>`? According to [Transition.js](https://github.com/reactjs/react-transition-group/blob/8dc9ad8d9412878a40312e418d389bf97f3794b8/src/Transition.js#L447-L449):

> By default the child component does not perform the enter transition when it first mounts, regardless of the value of `in`. If you want this behavior, set both `appear` and `in` to `true`.

Remember to also define in your css`.*-appear-enter`, `.*-appear-enter-active` properties as well. Typically, they are the same as `.*-enter`, `.*-enter-active`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this was posted a while ago, and that you have since switched to React-spring in your code.  However, if you are still interested, or if anyone else might still be interested,I found a couple of good tutorial videos that might help you use React-transition-group in the future.

- [React Transition Group Tutorial](https://youtu.be/1h-yZQQnrHg)
- [React Animations Tutorial using React Transition Group](https://youtu.be/BZRyIOrWfHU)

These youtube videos are pretty detailed.

Also, here are the docs for React-transition-group:
[ReactCommunity React-transition-group](https://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/)